# How to edit this url with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a godaddy linux server and I am wanting to edit my url's

Here is an example of 3 url's from my website

1. www.website.com/b.php?n=30&t=big
2. www.website.com/b.php?n=20&t=medium
3. www.website.com/b.php?n=10&t=small

I would like to be able to change them to

1. www.website.com/30/big
2. www.website.com/20/medium
3. www.website.com/10/small

MY IMAGE CODE

```
echo '<img src="gifs/' . $_GET["t"] . '/' . $_GET["n"] . '.gif">';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change them by changing all the links on your site from the `/b.php?n=30&t=big` style links to the `/30/big` style links. Then you can put these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*) /b.php?n=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

this will change the URI's back to the ones that route through `b.php`.

In the event that you have old URL's floating around the internet and they need to be changed to the new ones, you can use these in the same htaccess files:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /b\.php\?n=([^&]+)&t=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?b\.php$ /%1/%2 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect the browser (or google index bot) to point permanently to the new URLs.

Comment: So I should shove all that in the .htaccess file and it should work?

Comment: @user1616846 if you have other rules in the htaccess, or other request processing directives, you may have to think about where to insert it. Otherwise, you'll need to tweak it for your specific filenames, unless `b.php`, `n=`, and `t=` are actually what they are

Comment: Hey buddy it worked well! thanks very much. The only problem now is that no photos are being shown?

Comment: @user1616846 try adding `<base href="/">` to the header of your pages.

Comment: Right this is starting to get even more complicated haha. Yes some pictures have came out. Perfect thanks for that! However my main pictures dont show because I use GET from the url. I have added the code to the top of this page!

Comment: @user1616846 your images are probably relative links, and when you add a fake path, the base URI changes. You can either add the `<base>` tag or change all your photos to absolute links (that have a leading slash)

Comment: @user1616846 That's a completely separate problem than the one you have asked in your question, though. You can accept this answer if it answered your question, but if you need you can open another question to deal with your relative links

Comment: yeh your right! you have done your justice! thanks very much bro!